# Cannot use $(this) in $.getJSON in .each

Tags: this, each, getjson

Im building a custom Minecraft Server Status and hit a problem. The first version of this was successful but the code was rather long and I decided to make it better and shorter. The script is supposed to fill the elements of each .server but it doesn't work.

```html
<div class="server_status">
  <div class="container servers_info">
    <h1>My Network</h1>
    <div id="of the server" class="server" title="of the server" server-ip="0.0.0.0">
        <div class="name"></div>
        <div class="count"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        <div class="players">Loading player data <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        <div class="status"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="of the server" class="server" title="of the server" server-ip="0.0.0.0">
        <div class="name"></div>
        <div class="count"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        <div class="players">Loading player data <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        <div class="status"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- ..... more servers -->
  <span class="total"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
</div>
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function ping() {
  $( ".servers_info .server" ).each( function() {
    var name = $(this).attr( "title" );
    var ip = $(this).attr( "server-ip" );
    var id = $(this).attr( "id" );
    var total = 0;
    var call = "Get Avatar List adress";

//Set the name:    
    $(".name",this).html(name);          
//Gets the data:      
    $.getJSON("http://mcapi.ca/v2/query/info/?ip=" + ip, function (json) {
//Checks The status and applies visual effects:    
        if (json.status !== "false") {
            $(".status",this).html("<span class=\"l-online\">" + json.ping + " ms</span>");
            $(this).removeClass('blur');
        } else { 
            $(".status",this).html("<span class=\"l-offline\">0 ms</span>");
            $(this).addClass('blur');
        };
     });
  });
  //Sets Refresh rate of 10s
  setTimeout(ping, 10000);
});
```

I narrowed down the problem to the `$.getJSON` part. The data is retrieved correctly but cannot be placed in its respective DIVs. The only difference with the first version of the script is that I used 4 `getJSON` separately for each of the servers I wanted to display. Now using `.each` to combine it for all 4 of them and also $(this) to use relative objects.

I suspect the problem is in th usage of $(this) in .get but I'm nnot sure and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, the issue is the $(this). part. Inside the `$.getJSON` callback `this` no longer refers to the DOM object that triggered the event.

To fix this you can either:

Add a `.bind(this)` to the callback function. No changes required inside the function itself.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  /* all your code here */
  }.bind(this)
);
```

Or save the reference to `this` before `$.getJSON` and use it inside the callback.

```
var _this = this;
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
   /* replace all references of this to _this for example*/
   $(_this).removeClass('blur');

});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I fixed the problem just minutes ago by creating another variable with $(this)